# How to rename mongodb field using regex expression

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update the name of a field in the mongodb document using the regex expression on the name of that field but I can't, can someone help me to do it?
I have a person document that contains a field with the email of the person, the name of that field is like that `"firstname_lastname@gmail.com"` and I want to replace `"_"` character in all email fields by `"_dot_"`.
Here is what I did
:

```js
    db.getCollection("person").updateMany(
    {
      {'email.'+'.*_.*': { $exists: true }  
    },
    {
      $rename:{'email.'+'.*_.*': 'email.'+'.*_dot_.*'
    });
```

and here the structure of my document:

```json
    person {
    name: { .... }
    email:{
     firstname_lastname1@gmail.com : {
       .... other fields
     },
     firstname_lastname2@gmail.com : {
       .... other fields
         }
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the right terms! I don't think you are asking to rename a field, see [Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/). `person ----> email ----> firstname_lastname@gmail.com` is not a JSON document structure.

Comment: Do you really use an e-mail address as field name? Better ask how to change it to a value, e.g. `email:{address: "firstname.lastname1@gmail.com" }`, that would be a "proper" design.

Answer (score 2):

### As @Wernfried Domscheit suggested in the comment, you should change your schema to avoid using dynamic email address as field name.

Nevertheless, you can use `$objectToArray` to convert the emails into an array of k-v tuples. Then, `$split` them by `_` and rejoin by `_dot_`. Finally do a `$arrayToObject` to convert back to original structure.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "email": {
        "$objectToArray": "$email"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "email": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$email",
          "as": "e",
          "in": {
            k: {
              "$ltrim": {
                "input": {
                  "$reduce": {
                    "input": {
                      "$split": [
                        "$$e.k",
                        "_"
                      ]
                    },
                    "initialValue": "",
                    "in": {
                      "$concat": [
                        "$$value",
                        "_dot_",
                        "$$this"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "chars": "_dot_"
              }
            },
            v: "$$e.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "email": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$email"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LTAKhl9Lwtx) for your reference.